# How can I track all the downloads of documents from a sharepoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, auditing, download

I've done some research and it seems that the auditing option for O365 SPOnline is not available for downloading documents. Is there another optimal way to track all the downloads of my documents?
I'm afraid of doing it with JQuery because I don't really have the control of all the DOM items in a library.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

True, the SharePoint site collection audit log does not track view events in SharePoint Online! This is only available with SharePoint Server on-premises.

But you can obtain the information from the Office 365 audit log using the [Office 365 Management Activity API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/office-365-management-activity-api). The API is, however, only accessible to administrators. You can and should not query it directly from a user context in the browser.

One way to get the data would be to develop a background agent that subscribes to new events and writes them to a data store of your own choice. E.g. a SharePoint list, a SQL table, a complete SQL data warehouse or an Azure storage account. You can then query the data from there.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but I am afraid I won't be able to get all the information I need there (I need all the document metadata, track all the shares of the document, etc...). I'll give it a look anyway, thanks.

Comment: I know it is quite some work - but you could build a SQL Data Warehouse with the data you need. Inventory information can be pulled from SharePoint and linked with audit events from the Office 365 audit log. Depending on your needs you can have multiple dimensions in the DW including DimTime, DimFiles, DimUsers and DimEventType. The audit events go into a fact table, e.g. FactAudit, linked with the dimensions. This layout is known as an OLAP star schema.